# How to get node object from node ID

Tags: 8, nodes

in a drupal 8 custom module, how do I get a node object if I have the node id?
I tried :

```
$node = new Node($nid);
$node->save();`
```

but got this error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase::__construct() must be of the
>   type array, string given,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are a few ways.

If your context allows for [Dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8), inject the `entity_type.manager` service and use it like so:

```
$node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
```

If not you can still use the `entity_type.manager` service:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
```

If you prefer, you can use the `Node` class directly:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
```

Answer (score 7):

You never use `new` to create an entity, whenever you need to load it from the database or create it without loading it from the database.

In the case you want to create a node, you use `Node::create()`, as in the following example code.

```
  use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

  $settings = [
    'body' => [
      [
        'value' => 'The node body is here.',
        'format' => filter_default_format(),
      ],
    ],
    'title' => 'The node title',
    'type' => 'page',
    'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
  ];
  $node = Node::create($settings);
```

If you need to simply load a node from the database knowing its node ID, the code is much simpler.

```
  use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

  $node = Node::load($nid);
```

If then you need to load a node from the database knowing any other properties, but not the node ID, you can use the following code.

```
  use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

  $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties($values);
```

`$nodes` is an array containing zero or more nodes, and `$values` is an array describing the properties you know.